# Deploying a Laravel site with git without overwriting existing images

Tags: git, laravel, web-deployment

I'm currently working on a Laravel site where I use a git post-receive hook to checkout my repository to `/var/www`. It is simply running `git --work-tree=$WEBROOT --git-dir=/var/repo/web.git checkout -f master`

Everything has been fine so far, but I recently added the ability for images to be uploaded on the site itself. They are stored in `$WEBROOT/public/images/`, where I have currently been putting my own images. So far, all of my images have been under version control in git (first mistake?). Right now, any files uploaded to that folder are overwritten with every push. I tried adding that folder to `.gitignore` and removing the files from the cache, but it doesn't seem to work—the files appear to get overwritten no matter what.

How can I fix this, and is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

tl;dr: Before I was adding images myself in git; my site is deployed through a checkout. Now images are being added from the server side itself and I don't want them overwritten with a checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with a lot of wordpress sites, and have run into the same issues when people use the admin panel to upload images or add/modify plugins. My current workaround for this isn't the best method, but here goes.

**Short**
1. Use CI software to commit all to the webserver's master branch
2. Checkout my master branch to a staging branch on the webserver
3. Merge the temp staging branch back into master
4. Push the merged master back to my repository server so I can get files that were added directly on the server

**Long**
I have installed Jenkins CI (http://jenkins-ci.org/) on the webserver with the Git, Gitlab Hook, and Git Client plugins and I have run a Gitlab server (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/) to manage all my site repos. Both Jenkins and Gitlab are free, but there are paid alternatives that may work better.

I setup a project in Jenkins with my Gitlab repo url for the site I want, set the project to checkout to a sub-directory (my sites webroot in IIS), and tell it to checkout to a specific branch (staging) so it's not in a detached head state.

In the Build Environment Options, select Run buildstep before SCM runs and in the Execute Windows batch command enter:
git add --all 
git commit -m "Adding local files added/modified outside of Git"

Next in the Build options use Execute Windows batch command again and enter:
git checkout master
git merge staging

In the Post-build actions, I have it push my master branch back to Gitlab so my repo is updated with all the files from the live server.